# Bootstrap - Mobile showing restricted width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Could anyone tell me why on mobile this is showing space to the right and not full width. It seems to be fine on all other sizes.
http://showusyourcans.tmd-client.ca/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of your images. They are pushing the width. You have to make all these images responsives with class="img-responsive". See more at bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

Comment: I added those classes in yet it is still pushing.

Comment: Now it is another thing, let me see

Comment: Did you try to use container-fluid instead of container ? @user2721349

Comment: @user2721349 mark as right answer to help other people.